# Java Best way to acces buttons from a View on Controller

Tags: java, android, button

Ive just started to make things with android.
I like how it manages views, and how you can access to its elements in the controller throw methods like `finViewByID()` etc.

So I am wondering if there is something like this with java apis (Swing...) to access to the buttons in the view and manipulate it in the controller.

If there is nothing like that, which is the best way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because I haven't tested this in Java, but my answer would be almost definitely yes as other languages support this. You would have buttons in the view which would link to actions in the controller. So when that button is pressed, that method is called.

Comment: Thank you.
Maybe i didint explain very well.
I mean.
When you want to acces some button into a view in anrdroid you can use the finviewbyid method and get the reference for that button.
But i dont know if there is something as easy to get the references for buttons wich are into a different class.

Comment: If you have a controller you can pass him your activity and he can then call findViewById() there. So you wouldn't need to pass him every button for e.g. This is the easiest way to do it with android.

Comment: Yeah, what i need is something like this in java apis like swing.